# Creating a Round Edged form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, rounded-corners

```
private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
(
    int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0,Width-5, Height - 5, 20, 20));
    }
```

Ive got this Code from Stack Overflow but, this does not produce a clear edged window and moreover the minimize, maximize buttons are not displayed properly. Please Correct the Code. Is there any library(dll) to do the job in C#.

Comment: Add some more buttons onto the form and write code to close, maximize etc.

Comment: You See,the Edges of the form are not perfect when drawn,that's the main issue.

Comment: I agree with Tigran. It's trival in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can find interesting discussion here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/256570-how-do-i-create-windows-forms-rounded-corners.

Or if you have not sizable forms you can use an easy trick like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/cc963986.aspx.

But doing It well in WindowsForms is really hard. So if it can be an option to you, I would strongly suggest to use WPF instead. Especially I see you concern about not perfect rendering.